# SQL Server Check Constraint Nullable

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

For any check constraint if the BOOLEAN_EXPRESSION returns true, then the CHECK constraint allows the value, otherwise it doesn't. For a null-able column, it's possible to pass null for this column, when inserting a row. When you pass NULL for the AGE column, the Boolean expression evaluates to UNKNOWN, and allows the value.But what will happen in case of a Non null-able column if I pass null ?

Comment: check constraint is not false

Comment: Wouldn't this be far easier to just setup a table and test this yourself? Not only would you have an answer sooner you would actually learn what happens instead of just being told.

Comment: @SeanLange Already tried and done. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

> For any check constraint if the BOOLEAN_EXPRESSION returns true, then the CHECK constraint allows the value, otherwise it doesn't.

This is incorrect.  A check constraint returns a check validation error only when the boolean expression evaluates to FALSE.  `NULL` does not generate an error.

This is different behavior from `WHERE` and `CASE WHEN` clauses.

If the column is non-NULLable, then you will have a violation of the not-`NULL` constraint.  I think that is checked before the `CHECK` constraint, but the ordering doesn't matter.  You will get a nullability error.